# Customize grid lines in D3 grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new with D3 and I am trying to build a grouped bar chart using D3. I need my grid lines on the X-axis to be placed when the one plot ends. Currently it's placed at the middle. Also, currently the grid lines are appearing on top of the plotted graph, how to move the grid lines to behind the graph. In the Y-axis, is it possible to have my ticks start at 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 instead of the current, which show .5k, 1k etc

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="grouped-chart"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const data = [
        {
          category: {
            model: 'A',
          },
          type1: '1000',
          type2: '2000',
        },
        {
          category: {
            model: 'B',
          },
          type1: '2000',
          type2: '3000',
        },
        {
          category: {
            model: 'C',
          },
          type1: '1500',
          type2: '4000',
        },
      ];
      const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 };
      const width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
      const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      const svg = d3
        .select('#grouped-chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style('background', '#fff');
      const g = svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
      const x0 = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).paddingInner(0.1);

      const x1 = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.05);

      const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

      const z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#004c6d', '#255e7e', '#3d708f']);
      const keys = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
      x0.domain(data.map((d) => d.category.model));
      x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
      y.domain([0, 4000]);

      

      const gX = g
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

      const gY = g
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, 's'));

      g.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'grid')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom().scale(x0).tickSize(-height, 0, 0).tickFormat(''));

      g.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'grid')
        .call(d3.axisLeft().scale(y).tickSize(-width, 0, 0).tickFormat(''));

g.append('g')
 .selectAll('g')
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append('g')
 .attr('transform', (d) => 'translate(' + x0(d.category.model) + ',0)')
 .selectAll('rect')
 .data((d) =>
 keys.map((key) => {
   return { key: key, value: d[key] };
 })
 )
 .enter()
 .append('rect')
 .attr('x', (d) => x1(d.key))
 .attr('y', (d) => y(d.value))
 .attr('width', x1.bandwidth())
 .attr('height', (d) => height - y(d.value))
 .attr('fill', (d) => z(d.key));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bars should be drawn after gridlines to ensure that they do not appear over the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the y-axis tick marks, you can set the number of ticks to 4. Then they get drawn at the thousands: `d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(4, 's')`. You could also explicitly set the [tickValues](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues).

For the grid lines, you can copy the tick marks created by the axis and adjust their coordinates to go across the whole chart. For the vertical grid lines, you can offset their x coordinates by `x0.step() / 2` in order to put them in between the groups ([step() docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band_step)).

Also, I would recommend gray tick lines instead of black so that they don't draw so much attention. Lastly, the two colors you chose for the bars are a bit hard to distinguish from each other. Tools like [Colorgorical](http://vrl.cs.brown.edu/color) and [ColorBrewer](https://colorbrewer2.org/) can be useful for picking colors. Many of the ColorBrewer schemes are provided in [d3-scale-chromatic](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="grouped-chart"></div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // data

    const data = [
      {
        category: {
          model: 'A',
        },
        type1: '1000',
        type2: '2000',
      },
      {
        category: {
          model: 'B',
        },
        type1: '2000',
        type2: '3000',
      },
      {
        category: {
          model: 'C',
        },
        type1: '1500',
        type2: '4000',
      },
    ];

    // set up

    const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 };
    const width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const svg = d3.select('#grouped-chart')
      .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style('background', '#fff');

    const g = svg
      .append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    // scales

    const keys = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(1);

    const x0 = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(data.map((d) => d.category.model))
        .rangeRound([0, width])
        .paddingInner(0.1);

    const x1 = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(keys)
        .rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()])
        .padding(0.05);

    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => Math.max(+d.type1, +d.type2))])
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    const z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(keys)
        // colors picked with colorgorical
        .range(["rgb(88,181,225)", "rgb(26,101,135)"]);

    // axes

    g.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        // move group to bottom of chart
        .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
        // add axis
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x0).tickSizeOuter(0))
        // copy tick marks to create grid lines
        .call(g => g.selectAll('.tick > line')
          // skip last tick since there's no group after it
          .filter((d, i, nodes) => i < nodes.length - 1)
          .clone()
            .attr('stroke', '#cccccc')
            // move to in between the groups
            .attr('x1', x0.step() / 2)
            .attr('x2', x0.step() / 2)
            // make them go from top to bottom of chart
            .attr('y1', -height)
            .attr('y2', 0));

    g.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        // add axis
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(4, 's'))
        // copy tick marks to create grid lines
        .call(g => g.selectAll('.tick > line')
          // skip first tick since there's already a baseline from the x axis
          .filter((d, i) => i > 0)
          .clone()
            .attr('stroke', '#cccccc')
            .attr('x1', 0)
            .attr('x2', width));

    // bars

    g.append('g')
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(data)
      .join('g')
        .attr('transform', d => `translate(${x0(d.category.model)},0)`)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(d => keys.map((key) => ({ key: key, value: d[key] })))
      .join('rect')
        .attr('x', d => x1(d.key))
        .attr('y', d => y(d.value))
        .attr('width', x1.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', d => height - y(d.value))
        .attr('fill', d => z(d.key));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! Can I ask you one more question. In the graph we have labels A,B,C on X axis. Is it possible to have label, with Image with 2 lines of text - A, Text1 followed by another image on the second line with text, Text2.